# Python: php string into json

Tags: python, json

I am trying to convert a string into JSON format, using Python. This string is parsed from some PHP code and starts like:

'\x5B\x7B\x22id\x22\x3A\x2216376\x22, ...

In Python if I try json.loads() directly on that string, it seems to work but I think it's due to my text editor (TextMate) handling some errors (I suspect that because the following line is red but I can still run my script).

When I try in Python to pass it as an argument (imported from a .txt file):

json.loads(my_string)

it leads to the following error:
raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: Could you please provide the full string to reproduce your error?

Comment: Your string the hexadecimal representation of `[{"id":"16376"`. So it seems to be the start of some JSON. The question is what you are showing us? Is is the actual file content (the file contains backslashes? Or is a string in Python already (we see escape sequences wheer the backslashes and two hex value are one character)?

Comment: I can't copy the full string: it's 300,000 characters long, maybe that's why I am getting an issue?

Comment: I am showing the actual file content; when I copy that file content directly in my Python code, the json.loads() method works, but not when I work directly from the file

Comment: Try `my_string.encode('utf-8','backslashreplace').decode('unicode_escape')` to get the escape sequences out of the text. And if possible fix the file format at the source.